# In a LaTeX Beamer presentation, how can I have the numbering in the title of a frame with framebreaks to continue from the previous one?

Tags: beamer

In a LaTeX Beamer presentation, how can I have the numbering of a frame with framebreaks to continue from the previous one?

So consider

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{The Title}{The Subtitle}

1

\framebreak

2

\end{frame}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{The Title}{Other Subtitle}

3

\framebreak

4

\end{frame}
```

Where 1/2 and 3/4 have the same "The Title". This will result in "The Title I" and "The Title II" for both sections. Is it possible to let the continuation count continue for the frame 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `beamer` manual explicitly warns:

> Do not use the option `allowframebreaks` except for long bibliographies.

and

> The use of this option is evil. In a (good) presentation you prepare
> each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a
> certain slide rather than on some different slide.  Using
> the `allowframebreaks` option invites the creation of horrible, endless
> presentations that resemble more a “paper projected on the wall” than a
> presentation.

it might be better to manually determine which content belongs into which frame by using distince `frame` environments for each frame. In order to avoid numbering the frames manually, you can define your own new counter, for example as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}
\newcommand{\mynr}{\Roman{mycounter}\refstepcounter{mycounter}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The Title \mynr}{The Subtitle}
1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The Title \mynr}{The Subtitle}
2
\end{frame}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{frame}{The Title \mynr}{Other Subtitle}
3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The Title \mynr}{Other Subtitle}
4
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see the point. I use the allowframebreaks rather for convenience as I always do a manual `\framebreak` which I could just replace with an `\end{frame}` `\begin{frame}`  and then I could use your solution... I wasn't aware that allowframebreaks is considered code smell...